# 'Easy' proof with sumsets

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I've been struggling to prove an 'obvious' fact. Let
$$
P(X)=\left\{\sum_{y\in Y}y:\ Y\subset X,\ Y\text{ finite}\right\}
$$
and suppose a set $S\subset\mathbb{N}$ is such that $P(S)$ contains an infinite arithmetic progression. Then there is some finite set $F\subset\mathbb{N}$ such that $P(S\cup F)=\mathbb{N}.$

The solution sounds straightforward: if the progression is $mx+b,$ choose $F=\{1,\ldots,m+b\}$ and tidy up to take care of duplication. Unfortunately it's not clear to me how to handle them.

Suppose you have a number $n$ with
$$mx+b<n<m(x+1)+b$$
for some $x$. You want to use $k:=n-mx-b$ which is in $F$, but what if $k\in S$ and $k$ is used in the sum for $mx+b$? Maybe you can write it as a sum with some smaller elements, but $k$ might be 1 or the smaller elements might be used in the sum as well. You could add $k+m$ to $F$ but this also might be in $S$, leading to an infinite regress.

I'm sure there is a simple solution—$P(F)$ is so big none of these should be problematic. But for whatever reason I'm struggling to show this. It's much too simple to hope to find a proof in the literature (where the relevant terms are "complete" and "subcomplete"), so I turn to math.se. Help?

Comment: Ah, do you mean $P(S\cup F)=\mathbb N$ instead of $S\cup F=\mathbb N$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Indeed, thanks for catching that.

Comment: It is not clear to me that you want to get rid of duplication. For example, if $S = \mathbb{N}$, then the conditions holds, but you can't get rid of duplication by adding a finite set $F$.

Comment: @CalvinLin: Here's what I'm talking about when I say duplication. Suppose 10, 20, 30, ... are in the P(S). I want to say: let F = {1, ..., 9} and take one of 10, 20, ... plus a member of F. But what if 10 is not in S and 10 is formed as, say, 4+6? Then I would be writing 14 as (4+6)+4 which uses 4 twice. This is not allowed, so I need more than just {1, ..., 9} in F. It seems obvious that there are finitely many additional terms that would suffice but I haven't proved it. (Technically, I don't know that it's true, but I'm quite sure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $P(S)$ contains $mx+b$ for all $x$. Now for every $a\in\{1,2,\ldots,m-1\}$:

- If there is any $my+a$ (for some $y$) that's not already in $S$, add *one* of them to $F$. Then all but finitely many of the numbers congruent to $a+b$ modulo $m$ are in $P(S\cup F)$, by adding the new element to the expression for $mx+b$ for each $x$.
- Otherwise add nothing to $F$. We *already* have all but finitely many numbers congruent to $a+b$ modulo $m$, because we can form $b+(my+a)$ whenever $my+a>b$.

All in all, we're now missing only $m-1$ times finitely many numbers, which is finite, so just add each of the missed numbers to $F$ directly.

Comment: Thank you. I had started considering such a construction after I posted but hadn't completed the proof. Interesting that the F is so large&mdash;I wonder how large it has to be.